# ASP.NET - Cross Subdomain encryption pipeline isolation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, encryption

There is **one instance of the application** which hosts clients mapped by **subdomains**, eg:

- Client X is mapped to  -> http://clientX.domain.com/
- Client Y is mapped to  -> http://clientY.domain.com/

**Administration** of all clients is being done from **root domain**:

- http://domain.com/

Now the situation is the following:

1) I log into http://domain.com/ a authentication Cookie is being attached to the browser.

2) I navigate to any http://clientX.domain.com/ I'm still being logged in.

I know that this behaviour is because the `.domain.com` wildcard value on `domain` property of the cookie. Removing that dot `.` apparently solves the problem but, actually it doesn't because any intruder could edit the cookie and add that dot `.` back, so he gets logged into any **subdomain**.

I know that the cookie is being encrypted using `machineKey` property, so this is why the cookie value is valid for **root domain**  as well as for **subdomains**.

What I'm trying to acheive is **hook-up into the encryption pipeline and Isolate the Subdomains** by using a slightly modified `machineKey`

After some reseach I came up to [DataProtector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotector) class

### Questions:

1. Is it suitable to use a custom DataProtector for **isolating encryption per subdomain**?
2. If yes how to implement a custom DataProtector?

Comment: What intruder are you talking about? If you mean a malicious user, you need not only authentication, but also authorization. If you mean a network attacker, you need SSL/TLS.

Comment: @Artjom B. Cookie values generated from root domain are being successfuly validated for all subdomains, also Cookie value generated for subdomainX is valid for subdomainY. All this is because all cookies are being encrypted using same machineKey. I'm aware of authorization but authorization is a late step in this pipeline. Before authorization I need to invalidate cross-subdomain auth tickets by using different encryption key. In such a way there wouldn't even be a chance for reaching authorization process.

Comment: Any thoughts about that?